# typedef function declaration with class - non-static member call?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

I have the following class, called HashMap, which one constructor can accept a user supplied `HashFunction` -- then the one I implement.

The problem I am facing is defining my own `HashFunction` when none is provided. The following is sample code I am working with and getting the error from gcc:

```
HashMap.cpp:20:20: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
    hashCompress = hashCompressFunction;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
```

Header File:

```
class HashMap
{
    public:
        typedef std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)> HashFunction;
        HashMap();
        HashMap(HashFunction hashFunction);
        ...
    private:
        unsigned int hashCompressFunction(const std::string& s);
        HashFunction hashCompress;
}
```

Source File:

```
unsigned int HashMap::hashCompressFunction(const std::string& s) 
{
    ... my ultra cool hash ...

    return some_unsigned_int;
}

HashMap::HashMap()
{
    ...
    hashCompress = hashCompressFunction;
    ...
}

HashMap::HashMap(HashFunction hf)
{
    ...
    hashCompress = hf;
    ...
}
```

Comment: `hashCompressFunction` is a member function, it has different signature with standalone function.

Comment: there is a reason most hash implementations take a functor instead

Comment: @billz okay, that makes sense. By removing my `HashCompressFunction` outside the class, I am able to compile. However now the issue arise where `HashCompressFunction` no longer can access member functions nor variables within the `HashClass` -- IE bucket size. Is the only solution to make a static class?

Comment: @Adam: bad design. If your hash function needs to know the bucket size, it is not possible to write an external hash function. (This is why the standard library's hash interface returns a size_t: the hash map itself is responsible for reducing the size_t to fit the bucket size.) You don't need to remove `hashCompressFunction` from the class; you just need to make it static (but a static function still has no access to instance state, of course).

Comment: @rici at some point, your hash function needs to know the size of the bucket to limit its upper bound. So its not to unrealistic to have this requirement. The issue is not writing an external hash function, but one that is internal when no external one is provided. The syntax of the definition is what is tripping me up. Jesse Good posted a solution with static bind, but I believe a simpler one exists.

Comment: @Adam: no it doesn't. The caller of the hash function can do what is necessary to limit the upper bound (modulus, for example), as long as it knows what the range is. C++11 (based on the boost implementation) requires hash functions to be uniformly distributed over the range of `size_t`, which makes it possible to write a hash function without access to the hashmap object. If you insist on your model, though, pass the bucket size as a parameter to the hash function at every call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hashCompressFunction` is a member function, which is very different from a normal function. A member function has an implicit `this` pointer and always needs to be called on an object.
In order to assign it to `std::function`, you could use `std::bind` to bind the current instance:

```
hashCompress = std::bind(&HashMap::hashCompressFunction, 
                         this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

However, you should see how the standard library does it, with [std::hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).